# Different Context or Waker for each Future in Async Rust

Tags: rust, async-await, future, polling

I am trying to understand how polling works in a Async Rust Future. Using this following code, I tried to run two futures `Fut0` and `Fut1`, such that they interleave as following `Fut0 -> Fut1 -> Fut0 -> Fut0`.

```
extern crate futures; // 0.3.1

use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::{Context, Poll, Waker};

use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

use std::collections::HashMap;

use futures::executor::block_on;
use futures::future::join_all;

#[derive(Default, Debug)]
struct Fut {
    id: usize,
    step: usize,
    wakers: Rc<RefCell<HashMap<usize, Waker>>>,
}

impl Future for Fut {
    type Output = ();

    fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        self.step += 1;
        println!("Fut{} at step {}", self.id, self.step);

        {
            let mut wakers = self.wakers.borrow_mut();
            wakers.insert(self.id, cx.waker().clone());
        }

        {
            let next_id = (self.id + self.step) % 2;
            let wakers = self.wakers.borrow();
            if let Some(w) = wakers.get(&next_id) {
                println!("Waking up Fut{} from Fut{}", next_id, self.id);
                w.wake_by_ref();
            }
        }

        if self.step > 1 {
            Poll::Ready(())
        } else {
            Poll::Pending
        }
    }
}

macro_rules! create_fut {
    ($i:ident, $e:expr, $w:expr) => (
        let $i = Fut {
            id: $e,
            step: 0,
            wakers: $w.clone(),
        };
    )
}

fn main() {
    let wakers = Rc::new(RefCell::new(HashMap::new()));
    create_fut!(fut0, 0, wakers);
    create_fut!(fut1, 1, wakers);

    block_on(join_all(vec![fut0, fut1]));
}
```

But they are always being polled in round robin fashion i.e. `Fut0 -> Fut1 -> Fut0 -> Fut1 -> ...`.

```
Fut0 at step 1
Fut1 at step 1
Waking up Fut0 from Fut1
Fut0 at step 2
Waking up Fut0 from Fut0
Fut1 at step 2
Waking up Fut1 from Fut1
```

It seems, all of their Contexts are same, hence the Wakers for the each Futures are same too. So waking one of them wakes the other. Is it possible to have different Context(or Waker) for each future?

Answer (score 2):

The method [`futures::future::join_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/future/fn.join_all.html) returns a future that polls the given futures in sequence, instead of in parallel. The way you should look at it, is that futures are nested and the executor will only have a reference to the top-most future that is scheduled (in this case the future returned by `futures::future::join_all`).
This means that when the join_all future is polled, it passes the context to the nested future its currently executing. Thereafter the join_all future will pass it to the next nested future and so on. Effectively using the same context for all nested futures. This can be verified by viewing the source code of the [`JoinAll` future](https://docs.rs/futures-util/0.3.1/src/futures_util/future/join_all.rs.html#130) in the futures crate.

The `block_on` executor can only execute a single future at the time. Executors such as tokio that use thread pools can actually execute futures in parallel, and thus will use different contexts for different **scheduled** futures (But still the same one for JoinAll futures for the reasons described above).